# Proving $\frac{k-1}{k}$ is an attractor of the logistic map $kx(1-x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the logistic map $f(x) = kx(1-x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$. We already know $\frac{k-1}{k}$ is a fixed point of $f$, but my issue is showing it's an attractor when $k \in [1,3]$. There is an equivalent definition of attracting fixed points involving the derivative of $f$, but the definition I'm using is that the fixed point $a$ is an attractor when there is an open ball centered at $a$ such that all iterated maps based on points in that open ball converge to $a$.

I presume $B_{0.1} (\frac{k-1}{k})$ is a valid choice of an open ball, based on some initial iterations with differing values of $k$. Though finding the largest valid radius might lead to a cleaner proof. But how would I go about proving all iterated maps in the ball converge to the fixed point? Like most converging sequence problems, we let $\varepsilon > 0$ and try to find some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N$, $|f^n(x) - \frac{k-1}{k}| < \varepsilon$. I believe the biggest problem is that there is no simple way to express the $n^{th}$ iteration of $x$. I also don't know how I could find a good $N$.

Comment: To avoid the characterization using the derivative is one of the most curious choices one can make in this context. Any serious motive for it? (Of course one can mimick the proof of the general result that $f(x)=x$ and $|f'(x)|\lt1$ imply the point $x$ has an attracting neighborhood, this is tedious and it works, but why would one do that?)

Comment: That's how my textbook is ordered. It does seem uncharacteristically tedious. If we defined attractors using derivatives, I could see how a proof would emerge.

Comment: And they include the cases $k=1$ and $k=3$ (requiring specific arguments)? Which textbook is this?

Comment: Can you prove that $|f(x)-((k-1)/k)|\lt|x-((k-1)/k)|$ for $x$ close to $(k-1)/k$?